# Responsive Design edits with the use of CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to edit the look of of the two blue BaseKote product boxes on this page http://korekote.com/epoxy-coatings-1

I need to make the blue backgrounds full width after the responsive screen size of 768. So any screen size below 768 will have these boxes full width. What I am trying to match are the full width boxes above...ShieldKote and VaultKote. Note the 10px space between the two sections.

I am new to all of this type of css but really want to learn it. Below is what I have started with and for some reason it will not work.

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 967px) { 

.basekote-bondkote-column .mk-image-inner img  {
    max-width: 450px;

}

.text-blocks .vc_col-sm-6 {
    width: 100%;
}

.curing-profile .vc_col-sm-6 {
    width: 100%;
}


body .vc_custom_1447710738280 {
    border-right-width: 0px !important;
    border-left-width: 0px !important;
}

#basebondkote .mk-padding-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.vc_custom_1447710747652  {
    border-right-width: 0px !important;
    border-left-width: 0px !important;
}

.vc_custom_1447710738280 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> I need to make the blue backgrounds full width after the responsive
>   screen size of 768. So any screen size below 768 will have these boxes
>   full width. What I am trying to match are the full width boxes
>   above...ShieldKote and VaultKote.

The style rule you are looking for (which expands the width of the ShieldKote and VaultKote sections to 100% below a certain viewport width) is:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 967px) {
.mk-grid .coatings-product-column {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Where do I add the code or do I replace the code that is there.

Comment: It's usually standard to add @media query rules at the bottom of the stylesheet. If the rules are at the end, they will supercede any rules which appeared earlier in the cascade.